# Using OnItemClickListener on CheckBoxes in ListView with Adapter

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a row which is represented by an image, some text and a CheckBoxes. Whenever I'm trying to use the OnItemClickListener for the rows, the event won't fire up when clicking the CheckBoxes.

I also tried checkbox.onCheckedChangedListener but it gives me Null Pointer at findViewByID. I checked, the ID I am looking for is alright, no typos in there.

I'd like to make usage of this OnItemClickListener so later on I can play with the checkboxes. Any ideas?

Code:

ADAPTER:

```
public class FilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mFilters;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mPictures;
    private Typeface Bebas, DroidSans;


    public FilterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> filters, ArrayList<Integer> pictures) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mFilters = filters;
        this.mPictures = pictures;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilters.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mFilters.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_filter_item, null);
        }

        DroidSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");

        ImageView filter_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);
        TextView filter_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_category);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);



        filter_category.setTypeface(DroidSans);
        filter_category.setText(mFilters.get(position));
        filter_img.setBackgroundResource(mPictures.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Class where using the Adapter:

```
public class CheckinFilters extends Fragment {

    private ListView mListView;
    private FilterAdapter filterAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Typeface Bebas;
    private ArrayList<Integer> checkboxes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    public CheckinFilters() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkin_filters, container, false);


        l.add("Chill");
        l.add("Eat");
        l.add("Explore");
        l.add("Move");
        l.add("Party");
        l.add("Whatever");

        drawables.add(R.drawable.category_chill);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.category_eat);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.category_explore);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.category_move);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.category_party);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.category_whatever);

        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_list);
        filterAdapter = new FilterAdapter(view.getContext(), l, drawables);
        mListView.setAdapter(filterAdapter);


        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        Bebas = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/BebasNeue.otf");

        TextView mainHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filters_text);
        mainHeader.setTypeface(Bebas);

        SearchView filter_categories = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_categories);

        int searchImgID = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
        ImageView searchViewHint = (ImageView) filter_categories.findViewById(searchImgID);
        searchViewHint.setImageResource(R.drawable.ab_icon_search);

        int searchPlateID = filter_categories.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
        View searchPlateView = filter_categories.findViewById(searchPlateID);
        if (searchPlateView != null) {
            searchPlateView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_location_shape);
        }

        int searchViewID = filter_categories.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) filter_categories.findViewById(searchViewID);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

        return view;
    }

    private void save() {
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("first", checkboxes.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < checkboxes.size(); i++) {
            editor.remove("Status_" + i);
            editor.putInt("Status_" + i, checkboxes.get(i));
        }

        editor.commit();
    }

    private void load() {
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("first", 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            checkboxes.add(sharedPreferences.getInt("Status_" + i, 0));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        save();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        load();

    }
}
```

Layout I'm inflating for Adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ECF0F1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_picture"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sm_profile"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filter_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_picture"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Party"
            android:textColor="@color/enloop_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please share the code wht u have tried

Comment: I edited my question, please take a look :)

Comment: where are you calling onClickListener ? 
in your adapter or in the activity ?

Comment: @Darkie In the fragment, that's where I want to be able to use onItemClickListener, since the checkbox is part of the inflated row

Comment: @PopAlex-Cristian you have to call checkbox's click listener in adapter

Comment: I'm not trying to call CheckBox.onCheckedChanged, but OnItemClickListener, which should apply for the CheckBox as well, since it's an element I inflate as well

Comment: @Darkie. `you have to call checkbox's click listener`. No. One does not call listeners. One sets a listener. Then if a user clicks that view Android will call the listener handler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `OnItemClickListener` in `CheckinFilters.java`, you should add that code in `getView()` method of FilterAdapter. You are actually adding checkbox for every row but the id for all checkbox is same, so you can't apply customized code for every checkbox.

To be able to make use of all checkboxes you can put checkbox code in `getView()` method because it also contains an argument called position. So you can just get the position and apply `OnItemClickListener` to every single checkbox. That way it will work.

```
public class FilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mFilters;
private ArrayList<Integer> mPictures;
private Typeface Bebas, DroidSans;


public FilterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> filters, ArrayList<Integer> pictures) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mFilters = filters;
    this.mPictures = pictures;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFilters.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mFilters.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_filter_item, null);
    }

    DroidSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");

    ImageView filter_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);
    TextView filter_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_category);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);



    filter_category.setTypeface(DroidSans);
    filter_category.setText(mFilters.get(position));
    filter_img.setBackgroundResource(mPictures.get(position));

    if(position == 0) {
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)

            else {

            }

        }
    });
    }

    //Similarly add OnClickListener to other checkboxes.


    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: OK, but then how does OnItemClickListener actually work? If I click anywhere else but on the checkBoxes, it will fire up the event. There's gotta be a way of doing it the way I want.

Comment: @PopAlex-Cristian I have posted the code, you just have to check the position and add listener to the checkbox on that position.